# pandas csv write by ascii ignore encoding

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Pandas csv parser (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) supports different encodings:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv(myfile, encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', delimiter=',')
```

How do implement ascii ignore encoding case for my dataframe?

```
encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas doesn't seem to let you do that.  I had to pre-process my CSV file before reading with pandas:

```
decoded = codecs.decode(myfile.read(), "utf-8", "ignore")
encoded = codecs.encode(decoded, "utf-8", "ignore") #probably superfluous
fakefile = StringIO.StringIO(encoded)
data = pandas.read_csv(fakefile, encoding="utf-8")
```

Possibly terrible if you have a very large CSV file, but you could read chunks of the csv file at a time.